# SqlConnection Array of ints parameter

Tags: c#, sql, .net, parameters, sqlconnection

This is a part of my query:

```
WHERE GroupId IN (@groupIds)
```

With @groupIds being a List of integers of IDs.
How can I pass that list as a parameter in a SqlConnection?
I'm trying:

```
return conn.Query<>(query, new { @groupIds }).ToList();
```

But that's not working.

Comment: Instead of accepted answer in the linked question see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/961113

Comment: you cannot do that unless and otherwise you make the entire stored proc dynamic which is not recommended

Comment: @Habib that's for strings, I need integer.

Comment: @MatheusLima, there shouldn't be any difference. You can use the same code, instead of `string[] tags` you will have `List<int>`